# No se muestra la notificacion de PLYER con python

Tags: python

. Hola amigos.

Estoy intentando agregar una notificación de PLYER con python con el siglo codigo:

```
from plyer import notification as ntf
ntf.notify(
    title="Notificacion",
    message = "Esto es un mensaje por 10 segundos",
    timeout=10
)
```

El codigo de arriba lo guarda como **notificacion.py**.

Al hacer doble clic en **notificacion.py** simplemente aparece una ventana negra y desaparece al instante, sin mostrar ninguna notificación.

Pero cuando ejecutó el archivo **notificacion.py** desde CMD de la siguiente manera **python notificacion.py** ahi si muestra la notificación.

Por que no muestra la notificación cuando se hace doble clic a **notificacion.py** ?

Comment: Porque los archivos con extensión `py` no son ejecutables, pero puedes crear un archivo `bat` y ejecutarlo: `@ECHO OFF

START "" "C:\ruta\de\archivo\notificacion.py"`

Comment: Pensaba convertir el archivo python a Exe y así no precisar que python este instalado en una pc. Por eso no aplique esa solución.

Comment: Por los síntomas parece que el doble-clic sobre un .py crea una terminal temporal en la que ejecutar el programa y tan pronto como el programa termina, la terminal es destruida, sin darte apenas tiempo de ver el resultado. Si es esto lo que está ocuriendo, podrías poner al final de tu programa una línea que diga: `input("Pulse INTRO para finalizar")`. De ese modo cuando el programa llegue a esa línea se detendrá hasta que el usuario escriba algo, dándote tiempo así a ver la salida antes de que el programa termine y la terminal se cierre.

Comment: @FranciscoJavier Usar START dentro de un .bat no arreglaría nada, pues `START notificacion.py` hace lo mismo que si hubieras hecho doble-clic sobre  `notificacion.py`. Lo que hay que poner dentro del .bat sería `PYTHON C:\ruta\de\archivo\notificacion.py`

Comment: @abulafia Yo no he escrito nada que no haya probado primero en mi portátil, al hacer `click` sobre el archivo `py` solo sale un pantallazo rápido de `cmd`, pero con el bat se ejecuta el arcivo de prueba que he usado... Por supuesto, tal y como lo he descrito, sin `PYTHON` en el `bat`.

Comment: @FranciscoJavier Perdona si te ha molestado mi comentario, pero yo también había probado tu método y no me había funcionado, y en cambio sí que funcionó al poner python en lugar de start... Bueno, que el OP pruebe cuál le funciona a él.

Comment: @abulafia No, no me ha molestado tu comentario, pero es que por este medio no es fácil expresarse con matices... ;-D En cuanto al ejecutable, solo es cuestión de tener bien configuradas las variables del sistema, a mí me funciona bien, como te he dicho...

Comment: Amigos gracias por comentar. La idea final es que ese script python lo convierta a exe y así distribuir por internet a todos los que no usan python. Como un programa ejecutable.Cuando convierto el script python a exe y lo ejecuto (.exe) igual solo muestra ventana negra un instante y se cierra, pero al final tampoco se ve la notificación.

Comment: Tienes dos posibles causas: o el programa da error, termina y la terminal se cierra sin dar tiempo a ver el error (como dijo Abulafia). O esta funcionando bien y, habiendo ejecutado el código, el programa se cierra.

Comment: Será que python sólo se ejecuta como python y no como exe. Será que estoy intentando algo que nunca pasará? Todos mis sueños de hacer programas para windows con python se esfuman y que python solo sirve para Linux? 

Comment: No, no es verdad. Se puede convertir en exe. Solo que estas teniendo algun error. Por que no pruebas la propuesta de Abulafia. O abrir tu exe con cmd (NO doble clic), para poder apreciar el posible error?